# How to add sub-menu (css) under actual sub-menu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, css, menu, submenu

How can I add sub-menu under actual sub-menu in WordPress?

On one of my website, I want the coral coloured menu (which contains The Sciences, Accreditation etc) to have sub menus when you hover over it. I can't create a sub menu of this as the coral coloured menu is actually a sub menu within wordpress. The top menu being the "why, how, what, who" menu at the top.

*If you check, DISC should be as sub-menu (dropdown) under The Sciences but not working as it should be.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,

~ Dipak G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple drag and drop the sub-menus under the sub-menu. Sub-menus can be pages, custom-link and anything from left side of menu page. And then css of a accordingly.

the series would be:

```
The science
    sub-menu(of science)
         sub-menu  a
         sub-menu  b
         sub-menu  b
Accreditation 
    sub-menu(of Accreditation )
         sub-menu  c
         sub-menu  e
         sub-menu  f
and so on
```

and if you want css then tell me.

add this css in your theme and css accordingly:

```
    .sub-menu-corel .sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
width: 180px;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 10px 0;
z-index:999;
}

.sub-menu-corel .sub-menu  li{
width:100%;
}

.sub-menu-corel .sub-menu  li a{
display:block;
width:100%;
color:#111;
}

.sub-menu-corel .sub-menu  li a:hover{
color:#111;
}
```

this is updated css

Comment: I guess you've miscalculated - I know that already. What I mean is I want to display 'DISK' as dropdown (submenu). Have a look to this screencast http://imgur.com/IYa2NkR and I am sure you will better understand.

Comment: you can use the updated css,you will need to do rest of css yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I have added some elements in the CSS provided by you and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by drag n drop by going

```
Appearance => Menu
```

Just place it as sub-menu of sub-menu.